# Lex & Yacc - Grammar rules

Tags: grammar, yacc, lex, context-free-grammar

I am trying to learn lex and yacc.

I am struggling to understand how to do the grammar rules.
My file has already been defined like:

```
fd 3x00
bk 100
setc 100
int xy3 fd 10 rt 90
rt
```

My output with the printf and printing to a file went something like this:

```
Keyword: fd
Illegal: 3x00
Keyword: bk
Keyword: setc
Number: 100
Keyword: int
Id: xy3
Keyword: fd
Number: 10
Keyword: rt
Number: 90
```

Here is my lex file - im only going to show part of it to keep this post as small as possible

```
fd                  {return FD; }

[0-9]+[a-z]+[0-9]+      {}  // this is the illegal entry 3x00
[\r\t\n]+               {}
bk                    {return BK;}
setc                  {return SETC;}
[-+]?[0-9]+           {yyval.ival = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER;}
int                   {fprintf(yyout, "%s\n", yytext);}
xy3                   {fprintf(yyout, "%s\n", yytext);}
fd[0-9]+              {fprintf(yyout, "%s\n", yytext);}

%%
```

Here is my yacc file. It is not complete since i dont know how to finish it.

```
%{

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

%}

%token NUMBER
%token ID
%token FD
%token BK
%token SETC
%token KEYWORD

%%



%%
main()
{


yyparse()


}
```

I am not sure how i would write the grammar rules for these. 
Can i make my own name for the expression?

can anyone help me with one example so i can see how to finish it?

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, tag it as homework.

Comment: You have around 40 questions with unaccepted answer. Take care of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules should be like this:

```
statement: command arg {printf("Keyword: %s\n", $1);};

command: KEYWORD {$$ = $1;}
        |FD {$$ = $1;}
        |BK {$$ = $1;};

arg: NUMBER {printf("Number: %s\n", $1);}
    |ID {printf("Id: %s\n", $1);};
```

That means, you should define the syntactical rules in this way. Separate alternative definitions by `|`, and write the desired actions in a `{ }` block for each rule. Finish each rule with a `;`. When you refer to the the tokens, use `$n` where `n` is the position of  the token in the rule. The rule header can be referred to using `$$`.

Comment: Updated. Do the others in the same way.

Comment: Im confused: Where can i learn how to write the yacc grammar i cant find any tutorials online that dont show you anything but a calculator. Do i define my own statements? Like: my_stmt:
        KEYWORD? NUMBER?

Comment: I think i can see what you are doing. so, statement: command arg
command = fd and arg = 100?

Comment: Yes, you're free to define your rules.

Comment: Can you be so kind to also add an example of how i would do an if statment like : if (color = black)
[
        rt 45
        fd 20
]

Comment: Can i have multiple statements?

Comment: Of course you can. First prepare your grammar using pencil and paper. Then design it using YACC.